# run move_base node and get costmap from text file

Tags: ros

The move_base node call the function makePlan:

```cpp
bool makePlan(
    const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& start,
    const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& goal,
    std::vector<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>& plan
)
```

I wrote a c++ program to randomly generate start, goal, and map, which is a 2d array of 0s(free) and 100s(obstacle), and store this data into text file.

How can I configure makePlan to take start and goal from this text file, and how to allow move_base to use the 2d array stored in the text file?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own `GlobalPlanner` by implementing a `GlobalPlanner` `Plugin` see: http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Writing%20A%20Global%20Path%20Planner%20As%20Plugin%20in%20ROS

Then frist step would be to copy the original source code of the `GlobalPlanner` to your own `GlobalPlanner` and make it work.

Now you can change the make_plan method in your own global planner and adjust it as you like.